# React Apollo mutation varaiables value from props

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I want to update my record in mongoDB document by materialId and supplyId.
I get supplyId to mutation from url path. I render  for all of the listed materials with "+" button. How to pass props to mutation variable? I tried this was, but it's bad.

```
materialId: {material.id},
```

[Scren from React Developers Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCCUo.jpg)

```
        <Query
      query={gql`
        {
          materials {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      `}
    >
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (loading) return <div>Fetching</div>;
        if (error) return <div>Error</div>;
        else
          return (
            <div>
              Materials to add:
              <ul>
                {data.materials.map(material => (
                  <li id={material.id} key={material.id}>
                    {material.name} |
                    <Mutation
                      mutation={SUPPLY_MUTATION}
                      propsId={material.id}
                      variables={{
                        materialId: "get material.id Here",
                        supplyId: this.props.match.params.id
                      }}
                    >
                      {supplyMutation => (
                        <button onClick={supplyMutation}>+</button>
                      )}
                    </Mutation>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          );
      }}
    </Query>
```

Comment: materialId: material.id

Answer (score 0):

*You should use :*

```
materialId: material.id
```